# Can't Import Excel data to Mysql

Tags: mysql, phpexcel

I've following the step from this website [https://www.webslesson.info/2018/04/how-to-import-excel-data-into-mysql-database-using-codeigniter.html#comment-form][1]

but when I trying to import the data, my database data still empty

My Import Function in Controller :

```
 public function import()
 {
  if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
   $path = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
   $object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
   foreach($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
   {
    $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
    for($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)
    {
     $customer_name = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue();
     $address = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
     $city = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
     $postal_code = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue();
     $country = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getValue();
     $data[] = array(
      'CustomerName'  => $customer_name,
      'Address'   => $address,
      'City'    => $city,
      'PostalCode'  => $postal_code,
      'Country'   => $country
     );
    }
   }
   $this->pppmodel->insert($data);
   echo 'Data Imported successfully';
  } 
 }
```

My model :

```
public function insert($data)
 {
  $this->db->insert('tbl_customer', $data);
 }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Did you check the content of `$data`?

Comment: Did you mean my excel data that I want to import ? yeah I've check it ...

Comment: No.. I mean the content of the variable `$data`.

Comment: um, yeah I have check it ...

Comment: And is there something in it??? Do you get any errors?

Comment: there is no error just my data doesn't show in database

Comment: If your excel import code work, then you shouldn't have posted it (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Now you need to find out, why your insert doesn't work. But without knowing your DB library and without any error message - I doubt someone can help you.

Comment: I doubt too, do you have facebook or whatsaap ? I need help bro

Comment: I see. But SO is not a help desk. You must learn to debug your code. Start with [how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) and  [var-dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: ouh it's ok, thank you